# Multiple JavaScript calling

Tags: javascript

```
<button dojoType="dijit.form.Button" id="continue1" onclick="funct1();timeTracker._recordEndTime(); timeTracker._track(pageTracker, undefined, 'test2');func2(); " iconClass="dijitEditorIcon dijitEditorIconRedo" type="button" style="float:right">
```

I am trying to call multiple function like this but only the first function is called. How can make it so that every function being called?

Comment: Your problem is probably that an exception is being thrown, because otherwise all the functions would be called. Check the error console.

Comment: You sure `funct1()` invocation isn't causing an error?

Comment: That will call each function in sequence (baring errors).

Comment: You should be looking in your browser error console or debug console to see what javascript errors are happening.  Trying to solve problems without looking at the error log is like trying to drive with a blindfold on.

Comment: @alex all functions are executed without error when using them alone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're getting a script error in the middle of one of your functions.

Try running your code in Chrome, hit F12, and hit the "console" button.

Then reload the page.  You will see any script errors printed out to the console.

There are similar features in other browsers as well.  For Firefox you may want to install Firebug.  For IE, hit F12.